# Issues with Clang in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, clang

I am trying to use Clang in Cygwin. I tried installing Clang from the Cygwin setup. I wrote a simple Hello world! program but I got these errors

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/John/.babun/cygwin/tmp/foo-0b3b5b.o:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/cygdrive/c/Users/John/.babun/cygwin/tmp/foo-0b3b5b.o:(.text+0x1a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/cygdrive/c/Users/John/.babun/cygwin/tmp/foo-0b3b5b.o:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/cygdrive/c/Users/John/.babun/cygwin/tmp/foo-0b3b5b.o:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/cygdrive/c/Users/John/.babun/cygwin/tmp/foo-0b3b5b.o:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/cygdrive/c/Users/John/.babun/cygwin/tmp/foo-0b3b5b.o:(.text+0x79): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
clang: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I ran `clang++ foo.cpp` from the terminal after creating the file `foo.cpp` with the following code

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

It works when I use g++. Why does the clang error reference gcc? Any assistance on how I could fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the output of `clang -v` and `gcc --version`.

Comment: clang version 3.5.2 (tags/RELEASE_352/final)
Target: i386-pc-windows-cygnus
Thread model: posix.  
gcc (GCC) 4.9.2,

Comment: Looks like mismatched targets? x86_64 vs x86? Try adding `-m64`.